# Firebase Transactional Email Address Change alert email not sending

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I am using AngularFireStore and AngularFireAuth. I am able to create users via email and password. I am also able to verify a users email successfully. However, when I update a users email address there is no email sent to the user to alert them to the change. The email address update is successful though.

According to the [docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSGr4.png) I had the impression this process was automatic. 
Text from image:

> For security, when a user changes their email address, an email is sent to their original address so they can review the change.

The relevant code I have for updating an email address is below:

```
    firebaseUser: Observable<firebase.User>;

    updateUserEmail(newEmail: string) {
        return this.firebaseUser.pipe(switchMap(user => from(user.updateEmail(newEmail))));
    }
    test() {      
     this.authService.updateUserEmail('example@example.com').subscribe(result => console.log(result));
    }
```

Am I doing something wrong that is causing the Email Address Change transactional email not to be sent?

Comment: I assume the original email exists. It could be that the email is being filtered as spam. Try testing with a different email provider. Note the email is sent to revoke the change. The email change is allowed but the original email owner can revoke it via the link sent.

Comment: Yea, I've checked my spam folder and it wasn't there. I'll try a different provider, though I've been using gmail.